# How to link java code with php interface

Tags: java, php, eclipse

i have many java functions written in eclipse and i have a php interface developed. Now i would like to invoke my all java functions in php but i dont know how to link php and java any help would be appreciated.. please

How program works :
PHP interface developed there's an button find temperature
when i click that button it should invoke all the functions written in java in Eclipse and it should run completely and give an output.
PS: functions are working properly

I'm Stuck with how to invoke or link php with java code in eclipse

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using webservices between the two applications. unless there is another method that I dont know about.

Comment: Its an offline project.